# Why does the Firebase installation process give me an error? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Firebase in my flutter app to store some data, but when trying to install the sdk into my gradle, the gradle completely messed up and now it isn't supported. Even if I delete all of my changes, the gradle still says it is unsupported. Please tell me where the error is being created.
My top-level gradle.build file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' 
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app module build.gradle file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "org.RiverRipple.cibo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Please tell me where the issue is being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `minSdkVersion`:

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

to:

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

Also add the following in the `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

`minSdkVersion 21` is needed for Firebase to function

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this error for longer than I'd like to admit, but now I can move on. It is giving me a note in the debug console in red text, but I don't know what it means. The app is running fine, but I want to make sure this won't be problematic.

Comment: Note: C:\Users\kkanc\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.17.4-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\kkanc\Downloads\flutter_windows_1.17.4-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.12.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Comment: update cloud_firestore, use the latest version https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-installing-tab-